# Unauthorized access to TFS

Tags: c#, powershell, tfs

I have written a C# code whose exe is on a server. This code accesses the TFS to download some folders on the TFS. I am trying to run this exe (which is on the server) from my local machine using powershell.
I get the error :

> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TeamFoundationServerUnauthorizedException:
>   TF30063:  You are not authorized to access 
>   --url of the tfs  System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401)  Unauthorized

Code:

```
tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TFSProjectCollection"]), System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials);    
vcs = tfs.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
w = vcs.CreateWorkspace(Environment.MachineName + "-" + g, tfs.AuthorizedIdentity.UniqueName);
w.Map(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TFSFolder"] + application, applicationFolder);
```

Comment: @user1 that edit didn't improve any readability, and we certainly don't add "Thanks" to posts.

Comment: I suspect, you need to supply correct credentials to your PS Script. Your local user, might not have the appropriate rights on the TFS.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the parameter that passes the credentials to TFS. If your local user has permission it will automatically pick it up.

Comment: Thanks for this, this is also apparently the case with the TFS power tools cmdlets!